Parallel XY-MOS to split current
My custom 3D printer has got a 24V 400W heated bed. I need to power it with an external power supply as the 24V motherboard's heated bed output port can't provide ~17A.
I tried by using an SSR relay: it worked for a while, but eventually fused. I suppose due to the high duty cycle and temperature being in the printer chamber during print.
I then though about using mosfet drive to have a quicker response while producing less heat, but I couldn't find any mosfet drive capable of handling a constant current of ~17A @ 24V.
A possible solution might be attaching 2 XY-MOS modules in parallel to split the current, but I've read that is actually not that easy.
I'm then here asking how can I connect 2 XY-MOS in parallel or if there are simpler/better solutions. Maybe just putting the SSR outside the chamber would work, but I'm not expert enough to be sure about that.

What's an "XY-MOS"?

Your link 404's.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry, updated now

"couldn't find any mosfet drive capable of handling a constant current of ~17A @ 24V" Here are 4631 to choose from which would do that for you: https://tinyurl.com/2xbr2nzd

As long as the FET is fully on or fully off then a fet  with somewhat better voltage and current ratings should be all you need and there are many such available. The fet should have a low Rdson  =  resistance so that the almost 20 amps which is passing does not cause excessive heating. From P = I squared X R at 17A and 10 million on resistance you would get almost three watts of heating. A  TO220  or similar package device on a modest heatsink would andle it but surface mount devices would generally not be able to dissipate hat much power without extra care.

@winny I've seen mosfet capable of handling the current and tension I need, however, they're missing a drive circuit. I'm an IT engineer, so not much expert in electronics, can I just use it directly? Or can I alternatively swap the mosfet on the xy-mos drive circuit?

Neither is the "XY" module you linked to. Depends on what you have to drive it with. If 3.3 V GPIO, your heating control hysteresis is slow, so speed isn't much of a concern but you need to pick one with low enough Vgth (gate threshold voltage) to sustain 17 A and low voltage drop at 3.3 V.

@AlessandroMuzzi Just add a MOSFET driver. If this is to be a low-side device, there are some very cheap options. A FAN3111, a 1EDN7512, an MCP1416... You don't need anything particularly fancy, since this isn't something you intend to switch rapidly.

@winny I don't know what selection criteria you used but dissipation is high enough that he'll need some mix of good Rdson / heatsink / thermal resistance. You may how allowed for that. (On phone. Digi-Key clunky)

@RussellMcMahon 20+ A and 40+ V IIRC. Yes, some will certainly require heatsink. Many would be unsuitable without a >3.3 V gate drive. Still, plenty of options available.

I appreciate all of your comments. In the end, I chose to take a different route for the time being. The SSR that was referenced in the query was (incorrectly) positioned inside the printer's hot chamber, which reaches ~50° while printing. I assume that the SSR failed because the heat reduced its handling capabilities. As of right now, the SSR is outside the chamber and operating dependably. Should SSR break again, I will come back to this method.
